# what is the difference between personal access token and json web token for user Authentication?

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-5, jwt, laravel-passport

I know  we can use json web token for user authentication in web application.
The app client sends a couple username and password to application server, web application server return a JSON web token to app client.

Today, I read  some passages about personal access token  in Laravel 5.4 document . But, I'm not sure whether they are a meaning. what is personal access token?  The personal access token in Laravel is equivalent to JSON web token for user authentication?

Who can help me?

Comment: where do you read that? can you give me the url?

Comment: @M-N, this is url:https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/passport#personal-access-tokens

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the [definition](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/passport#personal-access-tokens)

> ## Personal access token
>
> Sometimes, your users may want to issue access tokens to themselves without going through the typical authorization code redirect flow. Allowing users to issue tokens to themselves via your application's UI can be useful for allowing users to experiment with your API or may serve as a simpler approach to issuing access tokens in general.

A personal access token is just a JWT(Json Web Token) created for user authentication with your own frontend to offer your users a dashboard for managing personal access tokens instead of using the user/password form.

Comment: Thanks , @pedrofb . I still don't quite understand. If person accesss token is   part  of OAUTH2.0 ?  I know that oauth2.0  has four  authorization grant types, , respectively is: authorization code, implicit, resource owner password  credentials, and client credentials. Is it related to these grant type?

Comment: "Personal" access token is a concept not defined in Oauth2.0. This is a proprietary function of Laravel. Seems it is intended to simplify to clients getting an authentication token for testing. From the point of view of Oauth2 an access token is opaque. The grant type is the flow of how an access token is requested.

Comment: Hi @shaun, did you check the answer? Do you need additional clarifications?

Comment: I read your answer but still I can't understand what is usage for personal access token .

Comment: @mhndev: The primary OAuth2 grant types are implemented in Passport. However,  Passport also allows you to issue access tokens IN LIEU of an OAuth2 flow. So, basically you can ignore best practices as defined by OAuth2 and just issue tokens under your own logic/flow, if you're into or require it.